# Gelatin for clearer beer

Tags: additives, clarity, fining, techniques

Does gelatin work for clarifying beer?  If so:

- How much do you use?
- When do you add it?
- How do you prepare it? (Do you boil it in water? How much water to dissolve the gelatin?)

Comment: If you add a space between the dash and your question you'll get a list instead of one long line.

Comment: excellent, i was wondering how people did that...

Comment: http://brewadvice.com/editing-help

Comment: Its actually two spaces not one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gelatin is used post fermentation.  Irish moss (and whirlfloc and supermoss) go in the boil.

Sometimes you can get a bit of yeast or chill haze even with kettle finings.  At that point you could try gelatin to fix it.

Don't boil the gelatin - that makes jello.  Instead, boil 1 cup of water by itself.  Take off the heat for a minute or so then whisk in 1 packet of unflavored gelatin.  Then add that to your fermenter or keg.  You may notice some improvement in 24 hrs, but it usually takes 3-4 days to completely clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  Winemakers use it as a fining agent.

[BYO question about fining](http://www.byo.com/stories/wizard/article/section/121-mr-wizard/1687-would-fining-with-gelatin-have-an-adverse-effect-on-naturally-conditioned-beer)

A more common fining agent used by homebrewers is irish moss, added during the boil.